# Can't understand a stack trace MVC .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC .NET app working in development but not so much in production.  Probably related to permissions?  Anyway, the production site is giving a stack trace, and I'm exactly sure where the issue is.

Is it failing on the first line (HandleReturnMessage)?  Or is the real issue on the third line which is my code: getPDF.

What does the error mean?  Parameter is not valid?

Thanks!

> [FaultException`1: Parameter is not valid.]
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14579646
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) +622
>   TMVCRepository.SFRepository.IRepository.getPDF(Int32 patientID, Int32
>   docID, String rootUserImagePath) +0
>   TMVCRepository.SFRepository.RepositoryClient.getPDF(Int32 patientID,
>   Int32 docID, String rootUserImagePath) +120
>   TMVCRepository.Controllers.ViewImageController.popupViewPDF(String
>   PatientID, String docID, String docType) +5255

Comment: When you call popupViewPDF (eew, PascalCase, not camelCase), surround it with a try/catch block.  Call `ToString` on the exception.  Log that.  What you have here is incomplete.  The result of `ToString` will not be.  Hopefully.  Depending on the remoting call.  What is that, by the way?

Comment: @Will Minor correction - you don't actually need to call `.ToString()` on an `Exception` - you can just write the `Exception` straight to the log.

Comment: Thanks, what's the best method of writing the exception to a log in MVC?  Looks like just write to a text file as normal.

Comment: @user1666620 That's not a correction. You assume there is one "log" and that its implementation converts the exception object to a string by calling `ToString` on it.  I'm not making any assumptions, I'm just telling him how to get the complete exception details out of the object.

Comment: @Will When I was writing to .txt files or to a console, I never needed to use `.ToString()` since that is called implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following suggestion of Will - I implimented a log in production and traced the issue by adding log calls before every line of the getPDF function.  Turned out the issue was a slight difference in the database between dev and prod, and the code was trying to call another function improperly.  So that's why the stack trace showed 'invalid parameter'.  A little confusing, it actually referred to code within the getPDF function.

Thanks!